# Android emulator 2.0 in Linux, screen orientation is always portrait

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm sure that auto-rotate is turn on, but I can't rotate screen to landscape mode in android emulator 2.0. Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot 1]

I'm opening Browser in emulator, it doesn't run in landscape mode (be the same with every app):

[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks a bug from version 2.0 (one of many bugs on this version)
If it's a bug there's nothing to do than wait Google to fix it, or you can downgrade your Android Studio, or what I recommend is to install Genymotion at least for Mac and Windows 10 is running OK. Good luck =)

Comment: Any updates on this one ? Is there any bug ticket reference ?